# Recursively name all .pyc.py files to .py files

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I'm trying to recursively rename all `.pyc.py` files to `.py` files.

**My code**:

```
import os,sys


def main():
    ffolder = raw_input("folder >> ")
    folder = 'C:\Users\Account Name\Desktop\Disney\toontown\\'+ ffolder +''
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
        if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
        oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
        newname = infilename.replace('.pyc.py', '.py')
        output = os.rename(infilename, newname)


while True:
    main()
```

It works fine but it requires me to type in each folder name. How do I make it do it on its own?

Comment: you can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk)

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`os.walk`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) to recursively traverse the directory tree.

```
import os
import fnmatch

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
     for f in filenames:
         if f.endswith('.pyc.py'):
             os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f[:-7] + '.py'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `os.walk` is the solution here. It can `recursively` find files in `subdirectories`. Try this:

```
import os,sys


def main():
    ffolder = raw_input("folder >> ")



    root = 'C:\Users\Account Name\Desktop\Disney\toontown\\'+ ffolder +''
    for folder, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
            if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
            oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
            newname = infilename.replace('.pyc.py', '.py')
            output = os.rename(infilename, newname)


while True:
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at `os.walk`. [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)
You'll want to call your rename function (`doRename(dir)` for example) on a directory. Have your function walk through the directory renaming all files then call itself with any directories it finds.